# RouterLink not work in Ion-Button after adding ion-tabs but work fine without tabs , How can I solve this problem?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

all working fine before adding ion-tab-button, I have buttons ionic with routing to another page

when i have added ion-tabs , the router link not work in button after click

where is my error ?! i need a solution .

this is my home.page.html

```
  <ion-header translucent>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>SERVER STORE</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content fullscreen>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">

        <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOptsOne" #slideWithNav
          (ionSlideDidChange)="SlideDidChange(sliderOne,slideWithNav)">
          <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of sliderOne.slidesItems">
            <img src="assets/{{s.id}}.png">
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>

      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" [routerLink]="['/iptv-list']" >IPTV List   </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" [routerLink]="['/sharing']" >Sharing List   </ion-button>
      </ion-col>      </ion-row>
      
            
            

  </ion-grid>

 
</ion-content>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button >
      <ion-icon name="speedometer"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>مباريات اليوم</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button >
      <ion-icon name="play-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>WATCH</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution :

adding `<ion-toolbar>` as parent of ion-tabs
solve my problem